# How to use calc() to get the current height of this element?

Tags: css, calc, css-calc

I have a div inside another div.

I want to make the inside one in the middle vertically.

I can use this way to achieve it:

```
calc(50% - 100px ) /* if the height of the inside box is 100px */
```

However, sometimes the inside box has a variable height, so I want to use something like this:

```
calc(50% - height )
calc(50% - attr(height) )
calc(50% - this(height) )
```

I tried many ways but can't succeed. Just like the picture below. It should be placed in the middle between the two thick srokes.

[image]

May I know how I can just retrieve the height value inside `calc()` function?

Update: I tried this according to jsotola's comment. But it says the property value is invalid.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `can't succeed` is a very poor description of what you observe ... I did a search for `css calc()` and the first hit pointed to an example .............. you really need to think about the result of `50% - height`

Comment: Sorry I can't quite catch you. In the picture I uploaded, the height is the height of the red box. It should be a fixed number like `235.4px` and the number is what I need to make the `calc()` works. I just don't know how to find the number with pure CSS. I don't want to get JavaScript involved.

Comment: I mean, I don't want to put an actual number in the formula. I want to use a variable instead, because with the content inside it, the height might change.

Comment: you are still not getting it ...... please answer this .... `what is the result of 5 - 10?`

Comment: sorry could you be more specific?

Comment: simple arithmetic question ... what is 5 - 10?

Comment: what does 5-10=-5 have anything to do with the question?

Comment: what is 50% - 100%? .... as in calc(50% - height )

Comment: if the 'height' is 100%, then how do I get the 'px height'?